# .NET MVC form versioning support

Tags: asp.net-mvc, version-control

I'm building an MVC based system which should manage requests, thats is, a user of the system fills in a request form, the form is passed to some authority for handling and there might be many other proccessing to the form in the way.

I want to be able to save History/Versions of the form, what i mean is, if a user fills in a form a year ago, and later on, the form has changed, when we open the user filled form, i want to see the version he filled(even if some fields were removed\changed in the current version) and work on it(thats including adding info onto his version and saving history of changes to that version)

I was thinking about having my forms correspond to actuall views, and when a user fills in a form, the view it-self+view-model is persisted to a DB, and when someone will want to take a look and work on that request, i will just re-render the view+model from the DB.

Is that possible using .net MVC? how should i approuch this? any other suggestions? better ways of doing such a thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to look for a revisions/versioning solution like:

[LINQ to SQL object versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356460/linq-to-sql-object-versioning)

Comment: thats not wat i'm looking for.. the problem is more MVC related then sql related.

Comment: Hi again MindFold : ), I suggest you to consider applying versioning at persistence layer -e.g. applying revisions to your entity- instead of doing it at VIEW level. so you could easily get revisions list, revision comparisons and more, just querying your current entity repository. hope it helps you : )